# 'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, typescript2.0, ts-node

I'm getting error in my Vs Code terminal and command prompt that **'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.** while i'm trying the start command in the terminal **npm run dev** and i have added my package.json file also.

```
{
"name": "tsnode",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "ts-node experiment.",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec 'ts-node --cache-directory .tscache' ./server.ts",
    "start": "ts-node --fast ./server.ts"
},
"author": "Mugesh",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.16.3",
    "@types/chalk": "^0.4.31",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.18",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.4",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
}
```

}

Comment: It's really simple - if you installed it locally in your project then you need to access it trough symlinks in .bin of node_modules ie:
./node_modules/.bin/ts-node

or install globally (the less robust solution, as versions will differ based on projects)

Comment: I have encountered the same issue in windows machine and removed the single codes in scripts > dev command  and it worked.

Comment: Be sure to not to have a package-lock.json and a yarn.lock at the same time in your project. Did you try to reinstall your dependencies?

Answer (score 281):

## You need to install ts-node as global

```
npm install -g ts-node
```

More information

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node

#### Update 2023

If you have installed npm > 5.2.0 version than you have npx automatically installed.

```
npx ts-node src/seeds/initPermission.ts
```

Or you can add script in your package.json
**In dev**

```
"seed:init": "ts-node ./src/seeds/init.ts"
```

**In production after making build**

```
"seed:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node ./build/src/seeds/init.js"
```

And run `npm run seed:init`

Comment: you are correct, If i try for a particular file in my root directory(ie., ts-node app.ts) its working, but its not working in my package.json run-scripts(dev)

Comment: This is not a great answer because it relies on other devs to install the same module globally.  See rsp's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454232/2500659)

Comment: No need to install globally.

Comment: This did not fix the problem. Trying to use Code Runner in VS Code. Typescript added successfully beforehand.

Comment: I think the issue is with the newer versions of npm on Windows. For more info: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1951.
Installing it globally fixed the PATHs and the issue. I would make sure the pack is in the project as well tho. I look at this as an OS dependency.

Answer (score 159):

I wouldn't recommend relying on globally installed `ts-node` in your own module as some of the answers here suggest.

If you do that then anyone who installs your module would need to install `ts-node` globally as well (just a usual `npm install` would not be enough) and then you will have a problem if two modules need things like `ts-node` globally installed but with different versions etc.

To avoid that, all your dependencies should be defined in your package.json and installed locally in node_modules.

There is a little-known command `npx` that is used to run binaries from modules that are installed locally in node_modules.

For example, see what happens when I install (locally) `ts-node` and `typescript`:

```
rsp@mn-r:~/node/test/ts-test-1$ npm i ts-node typescript
npm WARN ts-test-1@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN ts-test-1@0.0.0 No repository field.

+ ts-node@6.0.3
+ typescript@2.8.3
added 19 packages from 44 contributors in 2.157s
[+] no known vulnerabilities found [19 packages audited]
```

and then I try to run `ts-node`:

```
rsp@mn-r:~/node/test/ts-test-1$ ts-node -v
-bash: /Users/rsp/opt/node/bin/ts-node: No such file or directory
```

I can run it with `npx`:

```
127!rsp@mn-r:~/node/test/ts-test-1$ npx ts-node -v
ts-node v6.0.3
node v10.1.0
typescript v2.8.3
```

or I could give the path explicitly:

```
rsp@mn-r:~/node/test/ts-test-1$ ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -v
ts-node v6.0.3
node v10.1.0
typescript v2.8.3
```

In any case, I don't need to install anything globally.

Comment: so the solution is to add ./node_modules/.bin to the PATH? why isn't it mentioned at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node?

Comment: bottom line, your answer is: npm i ts-node typescript

Comment: Read through every single one. This is by far the best solution.
I am using the AWS CDK and encountered a build process where I can delegate TS compilation to build and test phases. This was a fantastic way for me to maintain that leverage and not rely on a global package.

Comment: This is simply brilliant.

Comment: So how do you run your project from there? `nodemon src/index.ts` would still make `'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 48):

The only solution that worked for me:

```
"start": "nodemon --exec npx ts-node ./index.ts",
```

Comment: try all of the answers, finally works this.

Comment: Worked for me.   I created a dev: instead of start: script, and I run it using npm run dev

Comment: This is great, but why did everyone skip your answer?

Comment: This worked so well, in my case I changed it to:  `"dev:watch": "nodemon --exec npx ts-node ./index.ts"` thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 47):

I just encountered a similar issue: on Mac OS `--exec ts-node` works, on Windows it doesn't.

My workaround is to create a `nodemon.json` like this:

```
{
  "watch": "src/**/*.ts",
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "ts-node"
  }
}
```

and change the `package.json` scripts section to

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon src/index.ts"
},
```

Comment: Documentation for `nodemon.json` can be found from https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files and then keep reading into the next section

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could do that with nodemon

Comment: Excellent for the very reason we can keep my global small, making it easy to pass along to other people

Comment: Thanks. Solved it for me.

Comment: This works for me. Nodemon local config is much better in my case.

Answer (score 36):

I ran into the same problem and found that it works by using double quotes instead of single.

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec \"ts-node\" --cache-directory .tscache ./server.ts"
```

**P.S.** This is 1 year after the problem. Not sure if package versions are a factor. Will confirm if needed.

Comment: This is mainly if you are on windows, otherwise you can use single quotes.

Comment: Had single quotes on my Mac. Brought to Windows machine, and double quotes OR no quotes worked... not sure if that's meaningful.

Comment: This was the real fix for me!

Answer (score 23):

If you work **under Windows** you can't use single quote in the json file. That is why **you have to replace all single quote symbols(') by the double quote symbols(")**.
But **between two double quotes(") you have to use escaped double quote(\")**.
For the current case you have to change the row in the file `package.json`:

`"dev": "nodemon --exec 'ts-node --cache-directory .tscache' ./server.ts",`

into the row:

`"dev": "nodemon --exec \"ts-node --cache-directory .tscache\" ./server.ts",`

Answer (score 14):

[Nodemon is for watching](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and rerunning node processes when files change. The local `ts-node` installed in the node_modules directory is not recognized in the scope of the `--exec` argument.  To get around this, some people have recommended installing `ts-node` globally.  As a user pointed out, that's not a good solution because it relies on packages external to your project and makes the `ts-node` in our `node_modules` pointless.

Edit:

With newer versions of nodemon, you can simplify this even further (note: you still need ts-node installed as a devDependency).

```
"start": "nodemon src/index.ts"
```

---

Previous:

To fix your solution, prefix `ts-node` with the `npx` helper, which will use your local `node_module` executables.

package.json, inside the `scripts` block:

```
"start": "nodemon --watch './src/**/*' -e ts --exec 'npx ts-node src/index.ts'"
```

An alternative approach could be to use the typescript watcher with the existing `node` command and the `concurrently` package.

```
"start": "concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"node ./dist/index.js\""
```

Same principle. One package watches for changes (nodemon & tsc) and restarts the second process (the node/ts-node server).

Edit 11/17/2021:
I returned this post to use it as a reference for setting up a prototype build and found the `nodemon` approach above was no longer working, it was now throwing the error:

```
''npx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I found a fix was to convert all single quotes to escaped double quotes.

```
"start": "nodemon --watch \"./src/**/*\" -e ts --exec \"npx ts-node src/index.ts\""
```

Guess something changed since I my original post. Hope that helps!

Comment: this is the right answer, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

For me deleting `node_modules` and installing it again using `npm i` was enough.

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar problem, but I have resolved by replacing

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec 'ts-node --cache-directory .tscache' ./server.ts",
```

to

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node --cache-directory .tscache ./server.ts",
```

Just remove the single quote(') and install ts-node globally

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem while using `nodemon`:

- I had `nodemon` installed globally, AND `ts-node` only installed locally.

Solution:

- I installed `ts-node` globally (still keeping the local dependency).

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the issue by removing single quorts around ts-node. as per below
"dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts"

updated as 
"dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec ts-node src/index.ts"

please note. my environment is windows 10 and npm version6.14.4

Comment: My original project was built on Ubuntu 18, and worked without issues. Moved to win10, had this error, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Like suggested in some answers, you should install `ts-node` locally and not globally.  `npx` makes it easy to use CLI tools and other executables hosted on the registry [as explained here](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner.html). Hence, can be used to run `ts-node` on your terminal and even scripts from your `package.json` file. For example;

Take this to be my `package.json` file

```
{
...
 "scripts": {
   "start": "npx nodemon path/to/file"
  }
}
```

Now running `npm run start` would not give any more issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following command

```
"dev": "nodemon --watch './**/*.ts' --exec \"ts-node\" src/index.ts"
```

This worked for me .

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you just need to re-install the package or packages.
Example `npm install -D ts-node` or `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

If your ts-node isn't working, as an alternative you can do the following:

1) Install nodemon locally --> `npm i nodemon`

2) In your package.json 'scripts' add the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

3) Now run `npm start` (this will automatically run node for you, but this WILL NOT COMPILE TS )

4) Open a new tab in the terminal/command line, cd the folder your working in and run `tsc index.tsc --watch`
This will compile your typescript. The only downside is you will just have to have both tabs open, one for running node automatically and the other for compiling automatically, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on windows. I found the solution for my issue was resolved when I corrected some misplaced `'`

Originally:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
}
```

Fixed:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec \"ts-node\" src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
}
```

The difference in case it isn't clear is that I no longer wrap `ts-node` in `'`

*** EDIT ***
I changed this based on the answer from @RoutesMaps.com above.  This solved my problem as well as removing the `'` but @RoutesMaps.com actually explains the issue resolution

Answer (score 1):

I ran this command after npm install ts-node.
This fixed my problem:

```
npm install -D tslib @types/node
```

Answer (score 1):

yarn add -D ts-node

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
}
```

'yarn start' now works

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
Without installing ts-node globally, just create inside your project nodemon.json file and put it there :

```
{
    "execMap": {
        "ts": "node --loader ts-node/esm"
    }
}
```

So now, you can keep type:"module" in your package.json and module:"ESNEXT(or smth that supports ES Modules)" in your tsconfig.json. However, you are going to get constant warning from nodemon that it's, I mean loader type, experimental feature but it's not critical.

In your package.json, in dev command for example just run nodemon path/filename.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mac these are the steps I came up with in order to fix this in the terminal.

1. Install globaly and use the returned file path with the symlink ‘ts-node’ and move this file into /usr/local/bin
2. Install locally without saving to package.json
3. copy folder in /node_modules into /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
4. Make sure the file is executable by opening /ts-node/dist and using the command `chmod +x bin.js`
5. run npm i in ts-node folder
6. Make sure that dist folder still exsists, if not copy it back over.
7. Test running ts-node in terminal, if it does not work it will return an error of which module needs to be moved over to ../
8. After ts-node runs be sure to delete the folder /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I found the solution for my issue was resolved when i do simply run this command first `"npm run build"` and than try it `nodemon` and also add in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"build": "tsc",
"dev": "ts-node ./lib/server.ts",
"start": "nodemon ./dist/server.js",
"prod": "npm run build && npm run start"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code-runner in vs-code then edit setting.json file

`"typescript": "tsc $fileName && node  $fileNameWithoutExt.js "`

Answer (score 0):

Write the the script like this inside your package.json file

"scripts": {

```
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",

"build": "rimraf ./build && tsc",

"start": "node build/index.js",

"tsc": "tsc",

"watch-node": "nodemon build/index.js",

"postinstall": "npm run tsc"
```

},

Then, npm run build

and finally npm run start

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when trying to run **nodemon** from a **Git Bash** but it seems to be working just fine when running nodemon from **PowerShell**. So, you should consider giving some other terminals a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Me helped this command

> npm i -D typescript

More specifically written there https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Please use `TSC --init`, instead of `TS --init`

Answer (score 0):

this error can occur if you have one version of ts-node installed in your project and another version globally.
To solve the problem - install the same version of the package

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same problem and came up with a hybrid solution, using npx to execute but via nodemon config (rather than package.json).

nodemon.json...

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "npx ts-node ./src/server.ts"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you install nodemon as globally then install ts-node also globally. If you install nodemon as -D (dev dependency) then install ts-node as dev dependency. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but my issue was that I had set the `NODE_ENV=Production` environment variable on my CI. When NODE_ENV is set the dev dependencies(where the ts-node was listed) won't be installed.

Removing NODE_ENV fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I removed it from dev dependencies and added it to dependencies. That solved the problem for my case.