# 'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file ts-node

Tags: node.js

```
{
  "main": "index.ts",
  "devDependencies": {`enter code here`
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.24",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "forever": "^4.0.3",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1"
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "request-ip": "^2.1.3",
    "upgrade": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

**npm start

> start
> nodemon index.ts
> [nodemon] 2.0.15
> [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
> [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
> [nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
> [nodemon] starting `ts-node index.ts`
> 'ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
> app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
> Reinstall after npm install -g ts-node, everything is the same error.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['ts-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764004/ts-node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: Error occurs even when installing ts-node globally

Comment: If you execute the ts-node command directly (without nodemon), does it work normally?

Comment: yes.. npm ts-node -v
8.5.0