unable to run my Node.js typescript project on Windows with TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"
My code works fine when I run in UNIX system. but when I tried to run on Windows system it is failing with following error
[nodemon] starting `ts-node index.ts --no-warnings`

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\{MY_PROJECT_PATH}\server\index.ts

following is my tsconfig.json file
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ES2022",
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"],
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true,
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "CommonJS"
        }
    }
}

following is my package.json
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "",
        "start": "nodemon index.ts --no-warnings"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {}
}


Did you try running through npx? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764004/ts-node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program

yes, I did try it but it is still the same
